# Chrome Bug 805525 in Android v62 and above crashing on css transforms and animations - is there a workaround?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, google-chrome

Update 2018-03-01:
  This issue has apparently been fixed in version 66.  Tested a number of pages in Android Chrome Dev and Canary, no crashes observed even during long and/or heavy runs.  I never did find a workaround, however 66 should be hitting Chrome Beta soon, and not too long after Stable so normal users should be able to run them again on Android in the regular version of Chrome within a few(ish) weeks.  Incidentally, this is the same update that Chrome will fully discontinue trust in Symantec-CA-based HTTPS/SSL certs.  I have noticed it seems slightly janky in comparison to before, but will have to test as this could be merely subjective on my part, or due to changes in my code looking for workarounds.  Further info can be found in the Chromium Bug report linked to below.

---

** Note:  If you've followed this post... I have to admit I thought I had a workaround by rounding values to only two decimals out.  However, I later realized this was causing a side-effect (because of an optimization I had made) of scale3d-ing some elements to 0,0,0, essentially causing them not to be rendered, and thus not triggering the problem for a long time.  When I temporarily removed scaling, said elements rendered again, and the bug was triggered.  Deep andhumble appologies, but-- problem not solved.  So, I have removed my answer.  Here are some things I have tried, none of which were successful:

Rounding transform decimal values to x.xx, two digits out.

Rounding transform values to straight integers.

Using setInterval instead of RAF to see if that was a factor (ugh!).

Using a style tag and .innerHTML to set dynamic transforms via css instead of the DOM (this was surprisingly efficient, but still triggered a crash just the same.

I've tried narrowing it down to particular transform parameters, numerical patterns, element nesting depths, just about anything I can think of to get around triggering a crash, and it looks like there is only one pattern:  every time you do a transform there is a chance of a crash.  It's a seemingly tiny probability, but doing scripted animations, even if you optimize to prevent repeats of identical transforms, makes the crash inevitable.  I can make it take longer, but I can't prevent it.

Now, I've seen similar reports all over the web regarding recent problems with CSS in Chrome since November, when version 62 update was pushed on the stable channel.  This last test, using a dynamically generates, embedded style-sheet to update the transforms was especially dis-heartening.  There doesn't seem to be a way around it except to wait for version 67 when chromium.org says the fix should come out.  That is months away for the typical Android-user.

This problem is not relegated to scripted animations either.  I've seen similar issues reported with CSS animations and transitions as well.

I've gone to the extent of trying a number of my animation engines from the past, all of which work beautifully on version 61 down to when RAF was available.  I've even written new, simple test engines, just for this.  I've tried a number of other developers engines.  Still crashes.

At this point, I think the only thing that can be done is to wait for the fix, and possibly get enough attention from enough people to hope they will up the priority.

They said in the ticket it's a problem with a code-optimization.  I would really like to see them revert that portion back in version 65 before it hits the stable channel, so the average user will not see this problem soon.  There's still time to generate another build and get it out before then.

Anyone who would like to see this happen, please go to the link below and put your two cents in on the ticket at chromium.org.

---

PREVIOUS UPDATE:  This issue has now been tested and confirmed at chromium.org as a bug in the GPU rasterization code, affecting up to version 66 of Chrome for Android, and appearing after build 62.0.3197.0 (the last build unaffected).  Their engineers are now working to fix it.

I am leaving this open for anyone who has run into this issue, so they don't think it's a problem with their code, and in case anyone happens to read it that can either contribute to the fix or offer a reasonable workaround until a patched build is released.  If anyone does find a workaround, please provide it as an answer here.

For those interested, the link to the ticket is below.  Here is an excerpt from the bug report:

> Tested the issue in Android and able to reproduce the issue.
>
> Steps Followed:
>   1. Launched the Chrome Browser.
>   2. Navigate to the URL: https://keithclark.co.uk/labs/css-fps/
>   3. Tap on any of the tab and try to access the game
>   4. Observed that Chrome gets hanged.
>
> Chrome versions tested:
>   64.0.3282.116 Stable/Beta, 65.0.3325.16 (dev) 66.0.3328.0(Canary)
>
> OS: Android 8.1.0
>
> Android Devices: Pixel
>
> Using the per-revision bisect providing the bisect results, Good Build
>   - 62.0.3197.0 (497604) Bad Build - 62.0.3198.0 (497674)
>
> You are looking for a change made after 497614(GOOD), but before
>   497615(BAD).

Previously:

Not quite sure if this is a Javascript, CSS, or Android problem-- but here goes...

Basic Question:  What do I need to do to keep my pages with scripted RAF 3D transforms from locking up Chrome vs. 62 and above on Android?  Is anyone else having this problem?

**Note: This problem may actually be a Chromium issue.  I have opened a bug report with Chromium Project.  Those interested can view the ticket here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=805525

I am leaving this open for now so they can view the full description, and in case it turns out I can fix my own pages with a change to my code.  But please, read on... ;)

Background:
My pages work great on 61 and below.  I manually updated Chrome on my Samsung Note 3 to version 63 stable recently, and found every page (not just mine) with complex, nested 3D transforms running on a requestAnimationFrame loop would lock up the browser.  A perfect example is a page from Keith Clark, who has a [CSS/HTML/Javascript proof-of-concept demo of a First-Person Shooter](https://keithclark.co.uk/labs/css-fps/).  Now, the mobile version worked great on my phone before.  After the update, it locks up.  My pages work really good, even on weak devices, till this update.

I've narrowed it down a bit.  If I clear cache, and uninstall updates, the stock Chrome (41) runs these things great.  Install updates to 63, 62, 64(beta), same problem.  I can't remember if I tested 60 or 61, but update to version 59 and we're still golden.  Firefox is fine.  Opera is well, Opera.  Same updates on desktop run great.

What I'm not totally sure of is if it's a problem with my phone.  No other problems, ever.  I know it's a little old, but it still blows most mobile devices off the shelf.  Android version 5, Lollipop.  Rooted.  If any of that matters.  Malware scans have always produced 0 with any AV/M app I've tried.  I'm very careful.

Anyway, if anyone else has had this problem, or knows of it...

What do I need to change in my code to make it compatible with current Chrome on Android?  Is this a problem I need to solve with code?  I've looked everywhere but can't seem to find info specifically on it.  All I can say is it's breaking my animations.  I can't even use dev tools to figure it out, as running a perf check from my computer crashes my phone so bad Chrome dies and loses the connection and any performance data gained, taking my phones wallpaper along with it!

I'm not picking up any errors from my script-- it's fairly basic.  I stripped it down to bare bones because I thought I had a runtime error, but nothing.  Is there a change with the way Chrome for Android interprets the CSS or does the layering or something?

Sincere apologies if this ends up being off-topic, as I'm not totally sure if this a coding issue, or just a problem with my phone in particular.  If it's a coding issue, that's what I need to know-- and how to fix it.

Comment: Ok.  Verified this is not just a problem with my phone.  I've tried it on a half-dozen Android phones with the newest update, and all of them freeze.  I can't check what's going on with Chrome's Dev Tool's, because  it crashes the phone's Chrome browser, taking the data and connection to PC with it.  Any suggestions as to what has changed in Chrome, and if there's something I can update in my code to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Android Chrome 62 is where this bug starts.  It affects all the Android devices I have tested it on, and only Android.  Versions I can replicate this behaviour on are 62, and 63 stable, 64 beta.  Android Chrome 61 is unaffected, so the change happened starting with Android Chrome 62 (stable released in Play store ~mid November-ish).  I've spent several days (all day) now reading google's reports, feature deprications and additions, etc.  It seems to be a problem with rendering and painting layers, only with 3d css transforms + an RAF.  Why now, and why Android?  Same pages work fine elswhere.

Comment: Just to note, the same pages work well even on weak devices with 41 to 61.  Nothing looks out of kilter from Dev Tools on 61, but I can't run tests over USB on 62 or above as it crashes the mobile browser on all the phones I tried and I can't get any data back to examine from any of the tests;  Also, if it's not crashed yet, and you check the options for rendering in Dev Tools: Paint Flashing and/or Layer borders-- it will freeze.  Usually it just stops responding, only sometimes it's the whole phone.  Definitely an algorithm related to rendering and painting layers with the transforms.

Comment: At this point my conclusion is that it is definitely a bug, _not_ part of a feature deprication or addition-- although this doesn't rule out the possibility that it is a bug that crept into a feature deprication or addition.  Likely it did.  But why only on Android?

Comment: Opened Chromium bug report:  Issue 805525,
at  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=805525

Comment: Hi @jdmayfeld did you find a solution? I have a similar problem